# How to use <b-pagination-nav> from Bootstrap Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to start using the  introduced in this [tutorial](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/pagination-nav/). The problem is that that I don't know how to make the  tag to work on my website. The explanation that is given in the tutorial on how to do that is very vague and as a beginner, I can't make it work.

I installed bootstrap and bootstrap-vue and added the .css and .js files the following way:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-vue.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
```

However, I don't think any of these add the  tag, because when I try to implement it, it is not appearing. At the bottom of the tutorial linked above, there is a section that gives information on how to import single elements. I tried to use the lines of code provided there but it did not change anything. Please, help me.

Comment: how did you created the vue project? using `vue cli` ?

Comment: I want to use the code on my website. I am not familiar with what a vue project is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On BootstrapVue website you will find everything you need in order to use it.

Your case is listed under [#Browser](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs#browser) section of Getting Started. Make sure you add all those dependencies to your page's `<head>`.

And, as for using it, you have to initialize a Vue instance on `window.load` event, at the earliest.

Example:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        perPage: 3,
        currentPage: 1,
        items: [
          { id: 1, first_name: 'Fred', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 2, first_name: 'Wilma', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 3, first_name: 'Barney', last_name: 'Rubble' },
          { id: 4, first_name: 'Betty', last_name: 'Rubble' },
          { id: 5, first_name: 'Pebbles', last_name: 'Flintstone' },
          { id: 6, first_name: 'Bamm Bamm', last_name: 'Rubble' },
          { id: 7, first_name: 'The Great', last_name: 'Gazzoo' },
          { id: 8, first_name: 'Rockhead', last_name: 'Slate' },
          { id: 9, first_name: 'Pearl', last_name: 'Slaghoople' }
        ]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      rows() {
        return this.items.length
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<!-- Add this to <head> -->

<!-- Load required Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<!-- Example #app template -->

<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div class="overflow-auto">
      <b-pagination
        v-model="currentPage"
        :total-rows="rows"
        :per-page="perPage"
        aria-controls="my-table"
      ></b-pagination>

      <p class="mt-3">Current Page: {{ currentPage }}</p>

      <b-table
        id="my-table"
        :items="items"
        :per-page="perPage"
        :current-page="currentPage"
        small
      ></b-table>
  </div>
</template>
</div>
```